# Shuffle part of array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle

I have a numpy array, and I would like to shuffle parts of it. For example, with the following array:

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.arange(15)
# => array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

I want to do:

```
shuffle_parts(a, [(0, 3), (10, 13)])
# => array([ 2,  0,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 12, 11, 10, 13, 14])
#            ^^^^^^^^^                              ^^^^^^^^^^
#            Shuffle those 3 values                 and those 3 values
```

The following would shuffle all the array: (Not what I want)

```
random.shuffle(a) 
# => array([10, 11,  8,  1, 13,  5,  9, 14,  4,  7,  2, 12,  3,  0,  6])
```

One way would be to use split / concatenate like so:

```
splits = np.split(a, 5)
random.shuffle(splits[0])
random.shuffle(splits[3])
np.concatenate(splits)
# => array([ 2,  0,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 11, 10, 9, 12, 13, 14])
#            ^^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^^^
#            Correctly shuffled                 Shuffled but off by 1 index
```

This is almost what I want. My questions:

- Can I write `shuffle_parts` where the indices are custom (parts with arbitrary indices, not restricted to modulos, and parts with varying length)
- Is there a method in numpy that I missed and that would help me do that?

Comment: Just shuffle sliced views of the array, for instance `np.random.shuffle(a[0:3])`

Answer (score 3):

It can be done directly:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random
>>> a = np.arange(15)
>>> s=3
>>> f=7
>>> random.shuffle(a[s:f])
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  5,  4,  3,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Indexing directly references the data, making this possible.

Comment: My code is running inside workers running in parallel, and I've noticed that all random values end up the same (for a given work batch). If I init the random seed with the worker index, that solves this problem. I don't know if this what you are warning about.

Comment: @BenjaminCrouzier No, the random algorithm itself is "insecure". I do not think it should matter though for programs that just need some randomness in them. I noted it in case you want to read more.

Comment: You're confusing randomness and security.  Python (and by extension numpy) use a pseudo random number generator, so it is not secure for cryptographic purposes.  For anything else, it's just fine.  This is not a weakness or drawback of the library or language - it's the same in any other language.  If you need truly random numbers, they have to come from a truly random source rather than an algorithm (and if you don't know if you do, you don't).

Comment: @user2699 Very well, I did not want to go into such depth, but the end of your comment I think drives your point - I'll edit out the note.

Answer (score 3):

numpy [slices are views](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) on the data below; so you can directly shuffle the slices:

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.arange(15)

random.shuffle(a[0:3])
random.shuffle(a[10:13])
print(a)
# [ 2  0  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 12 10 11 13 14]
```

you could implement your `shuffle_parts` function using [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) this way then:

```
def shuffle_parts(array, slices):
    for s in slices:
        random.shuffle(a[slice(*s)])

shuffle_parts(array=a, slices=((0, 3), (10, 13)))
```

or (depending on how you want to pass the slices to your function):

```
def shuffle_parts(array, slices):
    for s in slices:
        random.shuffle(a[s])

shuffle_parts(array=a, slices=(slice(0, 3), slice(10, 13)))
```

personally i'd prefer the second version (that way you could also e.g. shuffle the even indices: `shuffle_parts(array=a, slices=(slice(None, None, 2), ))`)...